# Is it possible to declare variable outside of switch scope in C++?

Tags: c++

In short, think about the (pseudo-)code below:

```
switch (n) {
    case 15:
        (keyword) customtemplate<15> t_var; /* I want it to be outside of switch */
        break;
    case 255:
        (keyword) customtemplate<255> t_var; /* I want it to be outside of switch */
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

t_var.do_something();
```

I wonder if there is some `(keyword)` that makes a following variable be global, or outside of switch-case scope.

The reason that I want such a weird code is, I can't declare template variable with arbitrary number of n, i.e:

```
int n = 15; // or int n = 255;
custometemplate<n> t_var; /* I can't do this */
t_var.do_something;
```

The `customtemplate` mentioned in this post is acutally `RS<n,k>` in [ezpwd-reed-solomon](https://github.com/pjkundert/ezpwd-reed-solomon). I want to declare `RS<n, k>` which is one of `RS<15,2>`,  `RS<15, 4>`,  `RS<15, 7>`,  `RS<15, 11>`,  `RS<64, 32>`,  `RS<160, 128>`.

Comment: If this is run time information, it shouldn't be a template argument. If you know the information at compile-time, you don't need the switch, just a helper template.

Comment: You would need to declare something with a common ancestor class.  If the package you're using doesn't support any, you may have to make a wrapper class which holds several member types of which only one is used.

Comment: @PaulKienitz, or he can use [std::tuple](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/).

Comment: You pretty much got the gist of it, I think. I'll just add to what @PaulKienitz said, since you probably don't want to write the wrapper class from scratch. You could use [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html) for a clean solution.

Comment: You might create a common base class for `RS<n, k>` that serves as interface. But if you can use it for everything is up to how `RS<n, k>` is defined.

Comment: I was thinking about some weird use of void* but probably is too sick

Comment: The RS thingy seems to have an untemplated ancestor `public_reed_solomon_base` that might do some good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple answer is "NO"!

In your case a different template instance is simply a different type.

If you can do something like you want, the question occurs what to do with this instance of any type. How would you later use this variable?

Remember: Creating a template instance is done during compile time! Running through a switch case is done in runtime.

Your code generates the same problem as in:

```
switch (foo)
{
    case 1:
       int bar;
       break;

    case 2:
       float bar;
       break;
 }

 ??? and now how the compiler should handle two different types ???
```

Again: Template instances are different types!

As others already mention here, you can use a variant type which contains exactly one instance of a list of given types. And it also contains a information which type is actually stored in this variant instance.

But I prefer using a available implementation instead of writing my own. For this see e.g. Boost Variant http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html

But as a resume from my experience: If you feel that you need a variant type you have strongly prove your design. As a hint: If you need a variant type you later will see that you every time you handle this variant you have to check for the actual content. I believe that this is often a violation of a good OOP design. It can help but for my opinion it should be avoided!

Comment: You could also use a common base class for all types or, as needed in this case, use a template wrapper class with a common base class.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Which is exactly what boost variant is. It can be used for related and unrelated types. i think there is no need to write the code myself.

Comment: I must disagree. With a variant type you still don't have access to member functions without casting. So you still need to differ between the types when calling the functions. So a variant class is still different from a abstract base class/wrapper class construct.

Answer (score 3):

As already written in the comments, you could use a common ancestor base class:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct RS_Base
{
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

template<size_t n, size_t k>
struct RS : RS_Base
{
    void do_something() override {
        std::cout << "n=" << n << "k=" << k << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    int n = 15; 
    int k = 2;

    std::shared_ptr<RS_Base> t_var(nullptr);
    switch (n) {
        case 15:
            t_var = std::shared_ptr<RS_Base>(new RS<15,2>()); /* I want it to be outside of switch */
            break;
        case 255:
            t_var = std::shared_ptr<RS_Base>(new RS<255,2>()); /* I want it to be outside of switch */
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (t_var)
    {
        t_var->do_something();
    }
}
```

---

*Update: Example for external struct/class*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

//External
template<size_t n, size_t k>
struct RS
{
public:
    void do_something() {
        std::cout << "n=" << n << "k=" << k << std::endl;
    }
};

//Internal
struct RSWrapper_Base
{
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

template<size_t n, size_t k>
struct RSWrapper : RSWrapper_Base
{
private:
    RS<n, k> value;

public:
    void do_something() override
    {
        value.do_something();
    }
};

//Usage
int main()
{
    int n = 255; 
    int k = 2;

    std::shared_ptr<RSWrapper_Base> t_var(nullptr);
    switch (n) {
        case 15:
            t_var = std::shared_ptr<RSWrapper_Base>(new RSWrapper<15,2>()); /* I want it to be outside of switch */
            break;
        case 255:
            t_var = std::shared_ptr<RSWrapper_Base>(new RSWrapper<255,2>()); /* I want it to be outside of switch */
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (t_var)
    {
        t_var->do_something();
    }
}
```

---

*Update: Example using a template handler function*

Doesn't work exactly as asked for in the question but might still be a solution for the problem.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t n, size_t k>
struct RS
{
    void do_something() {
        std::cout << "n=" << n << "k=" << k << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename RS_Type>
void handleRS(RS_Type t_var)
{
    t_var.do_something();
};


int main()
{
    int n = 15;
    int k = 2;

    switch (n) {
    case 15:
        handleRS(RS<15, 2>());
        break;
    case 255:
        handleRS(RS<255, 2>());
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, he's getting that template class from outside.

Comment: @PaulKienitz Ok I missed that. Well he could still create a wrapper... I will update my example.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Klaus that this isn't possible in the way you like; different realizations of a template are different types, so the `.do_something()` call (which, being called on a fully realized object, not a reference or pointer where v-tables might get into the mix) can't possibly know which version of the code to call.

That said, the problems caused by templates can be solved by templates. Instead of having the `switch` initialize something for use in code after the `switch`, or duplicating the otherwise identical code in each `case` (effective, but ugly; violates [`DRY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), have each `case` in the `switch` call a templated function that creates and uses the templated type appropriately. The remaining body of the function you wrote would migrate to this function, which is templated on the same count you used for the type, and the only action for each `switch` would be `return actionwrapper<15>(any, variables, beyond, t_var, from, current, scope, needed, to, perform, work);` (where non-primitive variables are ideally passed by reference, l-value or r-value, to avoid copy construction).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why some variable declarations are not allowed in a switch statement is: it is illegal for switch-based control flow to jump over a variable initialisation.
if you want to use the variable outside the switch statement, declare it before the switch.

Comment: The declaration is allowed.  the problem is you cannot access it outside the switch statement because it goes out of scope.

Answer (score -2):

Language-specific considerations aside, I want to approach with something different; which is called **object posing** in Objective-C.

You can introduce any instance of any class as some instance of some class, like so:

```
switch (someInstance) {
    case a:
    [ClassWillBePosed poseAsClass: [AClass class]];
    break;
    case b:
    [ClassWillBePosed poseAsClass: [BClass class]];
    break;
    default:
    ...
}
```

However, I doubt it is a solution.