# c++: Is it possible/recommend to declare variables based on runtime conditional?

Tags: c++, scope

Ok, I have read around and can't seem to find an answer that matches my question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970710/is-it-possible-to-declare-variable-outside-of-switch-scope-in-c) is about the closest I can find.

My case is: I have three sets of variables, and the program executes set A and either set B or set C based on a user specified flag. The values of all sets are also user defined. Currently, I have something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    //Set A
    double a,b,c;
    bool flag;

    std::cout << "Set Flag" << '\n';
    std::cin >> flag;

    if(flag)
    {
        //Set B
        double x1,x2,y1,y2,z;
        std::cout << "Set Variable X1." << '\n';
        std::cin >> x1;

        std::cout << "Set Variable X2." << '\n';
        std::cin >> x2;

        std::cout << "Set Variable Y1." << '\n';
        std::cin >> y1;

        std::cout << "Set Variable Y2." << '\n';
        std::cin >> y2;

        std::cout << "Set Parameter Z." << '\n';
        std::cin >> z;

        //Some operations based on set B
        a = x+y;

    }
    else
    {
        //Set C
        double t,u,v;
        std::cout << "Set Variable T." << '\n';
        std::cin >> t;

        std::cout << "Set Variable U." << '\n';
        std::cin >> u;

        std::cout << "Set Parameter V." << '\n';
        std::cin >> v;

        //Some operations based on set C
        a = t+u;

    }

    // I want to do more operations common to both sets here using data from selected set...
    // Write to file, etc.
}
```

Which way would be better: declare all possible variables first, or completely fork the code such that inside the if/else the code finishes, as the flag changes a few key steps, though much of what I want to do is similar.

The main difference between the conditions is that if the flag is true, the program uses a number of arrays/vectors, whereas if the flag is false is uses single values.

Comment: Are you asking about performance, readability, maintainability or some combination.  If you are doing UI at that point in the code, any performance difference is so trivial it should be ignored.  Readability and maintainability are usually best served by delaying the declaration of variables until you are need and can provide the value.  But merging any true commonality between paths also tends to improve readability and maintainability.

Comment: You should pick one single language.

Comment: You seem to be describing a case in which it is not practical to delay the declaration of `a` until its first assigned value is ready.  I'm never thrilled with those situations.  But you need to live with the requirements of the problem.  But you seem to be considering going to the opposite extreme and placing the declaration of `x` etc. pointlessly early.  I think that would be a bad idea.

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ questions!

Comment: @JSF I agree with not declaring the variables too early. Which is where my choice of declaring them outside of the conditional (so that they can be used in the common code area) or eliminating the bulk of the common code come from.

I don't want to repeat code, but I also have to deal with a case where I'm using vectors vs. a case where I'm not, and doing similar operations with each.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it is not possible or not recommended?

Back in the olden days in C you had to declare all variables in advance, but this is no longer necessary. You are free to declare variables when you need them and where you need them. It is easier, it is more flexible, and IMO more readable as well, as it flows with the intent.

Based on a runtime value, your program might take different directions, and do different things, which require different variables. If all code paths can go with a single set of variables, you could declare in advance and use them in any of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is good practice in C++ to declare variables as narrowly scoped as possible. So your example code does that par correct. For readability I'd put some of the code into functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

double inputDouble(const std::string& question) {
    std::cout << question << std::endl;
    double r;
    std::cin >> r;
    return r;
}

double handleB() {
    //Set B
    double x = inputDouble("Set Variable X.");
    doubly y = inputDouble("Set Variable Y.");
    double z = inputDouble("Set Parameter Z.");

    //Some operations based on set B
    return x+y;    
}

double handleC() {
        //Set C
        double t = inputDouble("Set Variable T.");
        double u = inputDouble("Set Variable U.");
        double v = inputDouble("Set Parameter V.");

        //Some operations based on set C
        a = t+u;    
}

int main() {
    //Set A
    bool flag;

    std::cout << "Set Flag" << '\n';
    std::cin >> flag;

    double a = (flag) ? handleB() : handleC();

    // whatever you plan with a
}
```

Of course your function can return more complex objects as well.

Comment: I think this is starting to get closer to what I am trying to do...might be able to change it around such that it calls certain functions based on the flag

But I think I will still run into the repeated code problem, as the biggest variation is having more variables (max, min etc for moving targets) and vectors/arrays in one condition, vs. having fewer variables for stationary targets in the other condition.

Answer (score -1):

How about using a union. Your complementary data sets would need to have same size or you have to watch out for buffer overruns...

```
struct setB{
  double x,y,z;
}
struct setC{
  double u,t,v;
}
union{
  setB set1;
  setC set2;
} common_field;
```

Comment: **WHY** What do you imagine is accomplished by that answer.  You are forcing a questionable implementation detail for which the compiler would do better than that left to its own choice, and you are obscuring the algorithm for no reason!

Comment: I appears to me that part of this question is about not repeating code. This is maybe more C than C++ but if data sets B and C are exclusive then why not use the same memory area. To be readable I would not reference B or C set in the common block but some opaque array...

Comment: How is that an improvement to simply using a, b and c in both cases?

Comment: @AmerAgovic When the scopes don't overlap, the compiler is very good at deciding to share storage for local variables.  You don't need to micro optimize details, like shared storage for local variables, in places where such optimization is insignificant.  But when micro optimization is called for, you still should not bother unless you would do better than the compiler would on its own.  For your suggestion, best case the compiler is so smart it see through your pointless micro optimization and does the same as the original.  But it might instead do what your code implies, which is worse.